# How to add tree panel to a grid panel column in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have grid panel. I want to add a tree panel to a column in that grid panel.

Grid Panel

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Tree Store

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: 'detention', leaf: true },
            { text: 'homework', expanded: true, children: [
                { text: 'book report', leaf: true },
                { text: 'algebra', leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: 'buy lottery tickets', leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});
```

For example,
If I want to this tree store to come under `Name: Lisa` i.e, tree expands when we click on Lisa. How can we do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is `treegrid`.

For modern toolkit, check [modern treegrid](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html).

For classic toolkit, check [classic treepanel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html) with multiple columns.